How to factor $(x-y)^5 + (y-z)^5 + (z-x)^5$
We see that polynomial is cyclic.
For $x=y$, $P(y)=0$ so $x-y$ factors polynomial. Because it is cyclic we instantly know other two factor $(y-z)$ and $(z-x)$.
$P(x,y,z)=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)*N(x)$
Because we know that P(x,y,z) has the highest 4th degree of $x,y$ and $z$ it must me that $N(x)$ is the second-degree polynomial.
I just don't know how the $N(x)$ would look like in terms of its coefficients.
If the coefficient for all members would be the same as it looks like in the solution it would be easy to solve this, however I can't logically comprehend why we can claim that given that P(x,y,z) has members with coefficients 10,5,1.

You likely want $(z-x)^5$ instead?

Should the last term be $(z-x)^5$ perhaps?

$N(x)$ is an integer multiple of $x^2 - xy - xz + y^2 - yz + z^2$.

Yes you are right z -x ,edited

Since we know that $P(x)$ is symmetric polynomial and his factor $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ is symmetric, we know that $N(x)$ is symmetric polynomial of second degree.So N(x) must be in the form of $k*(x^2 +y^2 + z^2) +j*(xy +yz +xz)$ .I tested for $P(2,1,0)$ and $P(3,1,0)$ but k and j are not correct

When $a+b+c=0$, we have this cute identity, $\dfrac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5} = \dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3} . \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$

OP arguments (from the question and the comments) are valid and lead to a quick result. First of all, considering the given polynomial
$$ 
P(x,y,z)=(x-y)^5 + (y-z)^5 + (z-x)^5
$$
as a polynomial in $x$ (with coefficients in $\Bbb Q[y,z]$) the elements $y,z$ are both roots. So $(x-y)$ and $(x-z)$ are both factors. Same argument shows that $(y-z)$ is also a factor. Then there is a polynomial $N(x,y,z)$ of degree two (after shortly working in the fraction field) so that:
$$
N(x,y,z)=\frac{P(x,y,z)}{(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}
\ ,
$$
an equality seen either in the function field of rational fractions in $x,y,z$, or as an equation between functions in $x,y,z\in\Bbb Q$ with paarwise different components/arguments.
The cyclic permutation of $x,y,z$ invariates denominator and numerator in the definition of $N$, and the transposition of $x,y$ changes sign in them in the same time, so both invariate $N$. So $N$ is a symmetric polyomial, having the shape $$N(x,y,z)=K(x^2+y^2+z^2)+L(xy+yz+zx)\ .$$
(So far, the question and one of the comments are recalled.)

Consider the specialization $z=0$ (the only one that makes coefficients $1,5,10$ appear somehow), this gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
K(x^2+y^2)+Lxy
&=N(x,y,0)=\frac{(x-y)^5+y^5-x^5}{(x-y)\cdot y\cdot(-x)}
\\
&=-\frac{(x^5-5x^4y+10x^3y^2-10x^2y^3+5xy^4-y^5)+y^5-x^5}{xy(x-y)}
\\
&=\frac{5x^3-10x^2y+10xy^2-5y^3}{x-y}
=5(x^2-xy+y^2)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This gives $K=5$ and $L=-5$.
$\square$

The above solution tries to give a sense to the $1,5,10$ coefficients mentioned in the question. Alternatively and much simpler we can use two specializations like
$$
\begin{aligned}
2K-L = N(1,-1,0)&=\frac{32-1-1}{2\cdot (-1)\cdot(-1)}=15\ ,\\
5K + 2L = N(2,1,0)&=\frac{1+1-32}{1\cdot 1\cdot(-2)}=15\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which lead to a simple system in $K,L$ with the same solution, $K=5$, $L=-5$.

Of course, computers have no problems to get the result, so we check:
sage: var('x,y,z');
sage: factor( (x-y)^5 + (y-z)^5 + (z-x)^5 )
-5*(x^2 - x*y + y^2 - x*z - y*z + z^2)*(x - y)*(x - z)*(y - z)


Hint:
I think the problem is $(x-y)^5+(y-z)^5+(z-x)^5$
Let $a=z-y, b=z-x\implies a-b=?$
$$(a-b)^5-(a^5-b^5)=-(5a^4b-10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3-5ab^4)=-5ab(a^3-2a^2b+2ab^2-b^3)$$
Now $a^3-2a^2b+2ab^2-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)-2ab(a-b)=?$

Is there a  hint for people with lower intelligence

Alternate solution/idea that should be helpful in the future. Let $a,b,c$ such that $a+b+c = 0.$ Then, they are the roots of the cubic:
$$P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = x^3+x(ab+bc+ca)-abc = x^3+qx-r.$$
Then, since $a^3 = r-aq\implies a^3+b^3+c^3=3r-(a+b+c)q = 3r.$ Also more generally if we let $p_n = a^n+b^n+c^n,$ then the same idea gives us:
$$p_{n+2} = rp_{n-1}-qp_n.$$
The lower values are $p_1 = a+b+c=0$ and $p_2 = (a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca) = -2q.$
So, $p_4 = rp_1-qp_2=2q^2$ for example. Finally,
$$p_5 = rp_2-qp_3 = -2qr-3qr=-5qr.$$
In other words, we have:
$$a^5+b^5+c^5 = -5abc(ab+bc+ca)$$
and in your case:
$$LHS = -5(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\sum_{cyc}(xy+yz-xz-y^2) = $$
$$= 5(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$$

Let $u = x - y$ and $v = y - z$.  Then $u + v = x - z$, so $z - x = -(u + v)$, and:
$$(x-y)^5 + (y-z)^5 + (z-x)^5$$
$$=u^5 + v^5 - (u + v)^5$$
$$=u^5 + v^5 - (u^5 + 5u^4v + 10u^3v^2 + 10u^2v^3 + 5uv^4 + v^5)$$
$$= -(5u^4v + 10u^3v^2 + 10u^2v^3 + 5uv^4)$$
$$= -5uv(u^3 + 2u^2v + 2uv^2 + v^3)$$
$$= -5uv(u^3 + 3u^2v + 3uv^2 + v^3 - u^2v - uv^2)$$
$$= -5uv((u + v)^3 - uv(u + v))$$
$$= -5uv(u + v)((u + v)^2 - uv)$$
$$= -5uv(u + v)(u^2 + uv + v^2)$$
$$= -5(x - y)(y - z)(x - z)((x - y)^2 + (x - y)(y - z) + (y - z)^2)$$
$$= 5(x - y)(y - z)(z - x)(x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + xy - xz -y^2 + yz + y^2 - 2yz + z^2)$$
$$= 5(x - y)(y - z)(z - x)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - xz - yz)$$
